# Is a visa required by a US permanent resident entering Canada on I-327 (Permit to Reenter the United States, Aliens Passport)

Tags: visas, air-travel, usa, customs-and-immigration, canada

Mr A. with Ukrainian citizenship and a green card (I-551) wants to visit Canada, by air, for about three days and return to the US. Mr A does not want to renew his Ukrainian passport and wants to use I-327 (Permit to Reenter the United States), Alien's Passport instead.

Does he need a Canadian visa?

The sources are conflicting:

- Canadian Immigration [says](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=593&top=16) that

  > as a U.S. Green Card holder, you do not need a visitor visa to travel to Canada
- Canadian Immigration [eTa page](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) says that

  > if you are travelling with a travel document issued to non-citizens, such as an alien passport ...you need to apply for a visa to visit ... Canada.
- Now [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_entry_into_Canada_by_land#United_States_permanent_residents) that when traveling by land only green card is required for Mr A.

Does the answer change for land entry?

Answer (score 3):

If travelling by **[land](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1053&top=16)**, only the green card is required (no passport or other travel document is needed).

If travelling by **[air](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1117&top=16)**, you need the green card **and** a travel document, either a passport, I-327 or I-571. So you'd need to apply for an eTA using your I-327, and present your I-327 and green card at the Canadian airport.